# Unable to create action due to name clash but no existing action has this name?

Tags: openwhisk

Creating a new OpenWhisk action from the command-line, the following error is returned.

```
$ wsk action create hello index.js
error: Unable to create action 'hello': Resource by this name exists but is not in this collection. (code 4923976)
Run 'wsk --help' for usage.
```

Looking at the actions already deployed, I don't see another action with the same name.

```
$ wsk action list
actions
/user@email.com_dev/example                                   private nodejs:6
/user@email.com_dev/hello_world                               private nodejs:6
/user@email.com_dev/testing                                   private nodejs:6
```

What is responsible for this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action, trigger and rule names must be unique within a namespace and package.

If there are no actions with this identifer, check for triggers and rules with the `hello` name.

Here's an example showing that actions, triggers and rules will clash when using the same names.

```
$ wsk trigger create clash
ok: created trigger clash
[17:41:41 /private/tmp]$ wsk action create clash index.js
error: Unable to create action 'clash': Resource by this name exists but is not in this collection. (code 5000008)
Run 'wsk --help' for usage.
[17:41:54 /private/tmp]$ wsk trigger delete clash
ok: deleted trigger clash
[17:42:06 /private/tmp]$ wsk action create clash index.js
ok: created action clash
```

This error can be resolved by using a different identifier for the action name or renaming the clashing resource. Actions can also be moved within a package to stop clashing with a resource in the global workspace.