# What is an OpenWhisk 'collection'?

Tags: openwhisk

What causes an action to give an error "Resource by this name exists but is not in this collection?"

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021298/unable-to-create-action-due-to-name-clash-but-no-existing-action-has-this-name), there is a specific case of name collisions between triggers, rules, and actions. But for me, there is nothing except a single action that I can not modify.

```
$ wsk -i rule list
rules
$ wsk -i trigger list
triggers
$ wsk -i action list
actions
/guest/getgoods/getgoods                                               private rust:1.34
$ wsk -i action delete getgoods
error: Unable to delete action 'getgoods': Resource by this name exists but is not in this collection. (code tv2u2w09oog8Z5y2ONGuGvLCvBErctga)
Run 'wsk --help' for usage.
```

For added info, I got an action into this state by using `wskdeploy` with a Rust action. I am able to deploy the same action (under a different name) with a `wsk action create` command just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error also comes while accessing action as a package, the name of your package and action is the same.
Try this

```
wsk -i action delete getgoods/getgoods
```

Comment: Yes, I had to delete and then set the package and action name differently in the manifest or `wskdeploy`. Thank you.